# How to pattern match enum in a single line in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Swift, if I have an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case foo(FooType)
    case bar(BarType)
}
```

I can pattern match with either `switch`

```
switch enumValue {
case .foo(let fooValue):
    // ... use fooValue
case .bar(let barValue):
    // ...
}
```

...or `case let`

```
if case let .foo(fooValue) = enumValue {
    // ... use fooValue
}
```

**QUESTION**: is it possible to match in one expression to check if it's of type `.foo(FooType)` to produce an optional `FooType?`?

The equivalent multiline version is:

```
var x: FooType?
if case let .foo(fooValue) = enumValue {
    x = fooValue
}
```

Something to the effect of

```
let .foo(x) = enumValue or nil
```

where `fooValue` is bound to a `FooType?` value or `nil` if it's not `.foo`.